# Crawling data from Web, When page loads data dynamically at end of page

Tags: java, web-crawler

I want to crawl some data from web using java, however I found that the page loads data when it reaches end of page. I am not a web developer and do not know which technology they use to load data when scroll reaches end of page.

Could you give me some hint? Which technology they used? How can I read data when I do not want use browser? ( I wrote a code with java using urlConnection to read data from site.

The site is something like this "https://www.healthtap.com/#topics/Women%27s%20health".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a common "problem" of web-crawlers bots...
some pages contains dynamically content added from contained sources.
this content can be loaded on page load or triggered (like your example - by scrolling down).
when the target page is downloaded and scraped the DOM structure doesn't, in most of cases, include the
html elements of the outer included data.

what i suggest u to do is to identify the source path of this data, 
that could be done by carefully checking the scrips on the DOM. and calling him as a secondary source 
that includes all the missing data you need.

edit:

in the example you linked- its easy:

```
      - install firebug.
      - scroll down the page to check the script that fires the request.
      - now you can see the link and the vars that are used for dynamicly adding the content.
```

www.healthtap.com/#topics/Women%27s%20health:

dinamyclly response link:

https://www.healthtap.com/topics/Women%27s%20health.json? extended_categories=1&auth_token=false&per_page=8&page=7&per_page=8&auth_token=false&generate_token=true

as you can see there a few parameters you can play with:

```
 1/ topics/ + the page firs value name + .json?
 2/ per page= num -> how much results to return
 3/ generate_token=true -> its a security value but just change it to false and it work fine....
```

now you can play with this link and load all the data you need and merge it with the main page you crawled.

tested!

Comment: Thank you so much. It is so useful. Could you let me know how you find dinamyclly response link:

https://www.healthtap.com/topics/Women%27s%20health.json? extended_categories=1&auth_token=false&per_page=8&page=7&per_page=8&auth_token=false&generate_token=true

Comment: As i said you can search the source code or you can install firebug - [link to firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), install it, and while scrolling down you can see in the firebug console which URL is being loaded.